# Vertical Partition MySQL table

Tags: mysql, join, partitioning

I am reviewing a case, where I have 200+ columns mostly varchar(100). The columns are from several external data sources like CRM / Demographics data etc. I cannot hold them in one MySQL table with ever growing number of columns.

The general query situation may contain columns from one or more vertical partitions.

- Is it a good idea to vertically split them? and join them on query?
- What should be the size of each partition (number of columns)? To improve performance.
- What should be the best JOIN matching condition?

MySQL version: 5.7
Storage Engine: InnoDB

Comment: What about horizontal partitioning?

Comment: The problem is with row size limit. I think horizontal partitioning will help for high number of rows, not with high number of columns.

Comment: OK, but tables typically grow vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: There has to be some rhyme or reason to the columns. Some column from one data source, some from another, etc. In order to really answer your questions, it would necessary to know more about the existing columns, and their sources. You just need to analyze what they are and their nature.

Answer (score 1):

- If groups of columns are addresses (street, city, state, country, postal_code), you could/should move multiple addresses to a single "Locations" table.  (Ditto for other logical groupings.)
- Are multiple columns really "an array splayed across columns"?  Eg, "foo1", foo2", "foo3", ...?  If so, the really *should* not be just vertically partitioned, but turned into multiple rows in the other table.
- If some columns are really numbers or dates, use the appropriate datatype (after cleansing the input).
- You say "most are `VARCHAR(100)`".  Make reasonable upper bounds; this will help (some) in avoiding row-size limitation.
- Are some of the columns "sparse"?  That is, most rows do not have entries for those values?  Collect then into a single `JSON` column.  (Or a couple of `JSON` columns, if there is a distinct split.)  If you have an old version of MySQL/MariaDB (you don't), simply put the JSON string into a `TEXT` column.

If you are still stuck with vertical partitioning, the number of columns and number of tables makes very little difference in the `JOIN` performance.  It would be better to look at the `SELECTs` to decide which columns to put in each partition -- Have all the searching in a single table (a `WHERE` clause hitting multiple table is often inefficient).  Having a partition that is usually unused may let you avoid `JOINing` to it.